# How do I attach an inline image to the email being sent by ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer, html-email, inline-images

How do I attach an inline image to the email being sent by ActionMailer? How do I test if image was really attached at a specific place in the Email?

Answer (score 1):

There is an interesting article about Action Mailer inline attachment here, which has some code detailing how to solve the problem.
Probably may be of help to you.

Check out
http://blog.thoughtobject.com/2007/05/26/5/

Answer (score 1):

Something like the [inline_attachment gem](http://github.com/JasonKing/inline_attachment/tree/master) may work for you.

Comment: Isn't there any way by which I can do this without using any gem or plugin?